# Different comparison types used in a way similar to if a in {b, c, d}:

Tags: python

I need to check if any of my variables are larger than a threshold.

Currently I'm doing
`if b > a or c > a or d > a` ... etc

Is there a faster way to write this (similar to  `if a in {b, c, d}`:?)

Comment: `if any(i > a for i in {b, c, d}):`

Comment: `if max(b, c, d) > a:` - doesn't have short-circuiting, but it does what you want.

Comment: @kaya3 Oh very smart!

Comment: `any(map(a.__lt__, (b,c,d)))` to have it all covered  :D

Comment: @schwobaseggl That will fail when `a = 5` and `b = 4.0`, because `a.__lt__(b)` is `NotImplemented`, which is truthy.

Comment: @schwobaseggl The only way to get short-circuit evaluation of `b`, `c` and `d`, other than using `or` like the original code, would be to defer them with lambdas. But the question says "any of my variables" so I think this isn't an issue.

Comment: The map version provided by @schwobaseggl looks way faster.

Comment: @MSH The `map` version is also not correct in some cases, see my comment.

Comment: @schwobaseggl If `<` causes an error then what you are trying to do doesn't make sense. But if `<` fails then it raises an exception - it does not silently fail by producing the wrong result, which would be far more dangerous.

Comment: @kaya3 Touché. I am advocating for the functional devil here anyway, being a fan of the generator expression :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the best approach, but I know the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in function can help with this:

```py
numbers = [8, 9, 4]
threshold = 3

if any(n > threshold for n in numbers):
    print("At least one is above the threshold")
else:
    print("None are above the threshold")
```

Comment: No need for the condition, `any` already returns a boolean. Just do `print(any(...))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think the point here is to demonstrate how to use `any` in an `if` statement, not to demonstrate how to print the boolean result of `any`.

Comment: @kaya3 yes, that sounds about right. I did realize the `print(any(...))` would be much cleaner though.

Comment: @kaya3 yep in the context of the question you are right, I just find it hard to look at `if ...: print(True) else: print(False)`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Fair enough, I edited to make it more aesthetically pleasing.